# Comparing Two Faces (From another images) EmguOpenCV (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I'm using EmguCV (It is .Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing library).
I need to compare two images and check if this is the same person in both images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But not directly in emgu, unless you want to make a lot of code. 
Have a look at this page https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/face/
Here you supply two images and get score back.
It should be easy implementing the API